# How to go about creating an Excel -> web -> PDF workflow automation?

Tags: excel, pdf, web, search, pdf-generation

I am looking for ways to automate a workflow that I daily execute manually, the outline of which is as follows:

```
> Receive a list of Company and/or Individual names as Excel or csv
> Run a search based on each of these names in three databases 
(the specifics are a bit detailed featuring the interface of a password-protected 
site for one and a specific search string for another)
> Save the output as PDF while adding keywords to filenames based on
 which database it was conducted on 
(such as '-wc', '-gc' at the end of filenames)
```

Its probably quite straightforward to accomplish this, however, having no programming experience and being fairly new to automation I'm a bit clueless as to where to start :)

I tried to find a solution on zapier but wasn't successful. Maybe even Mac Automator workflow could work, though not sure.

Thanks in advance for any leads

Comment: Look into using Azure LogicApps.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated